# 'and' assumptions in NL

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm not really looking for a 'solution', but what the term of the problems is called so I can move forward and evaluate solutions on a tricky dataset.

Given a simplified string of:

> Head and neck fracture

We can assume that there are two possible fractures:

- One of the head.
- One of the neck.

What is this specific NLP problem called?

Comment: Isn't the grammar incorrect? Shouldn't this be "head and neck fractures"?

Comment: *"What is this specific NLP problem called?"* << What specific problem are you asking about?

Comment: Also note that https://ai.stackexchange.com is often better-suited for non-programming NLP questions

Comment: This is about the scope of coordinating conjunctions.

Comment: @Stef I believe it can be used in this way, so I don't think it is incorrect.